# On click: New page + sub-menu stay opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal, submenu

I am working on a drupal 8 website. I installed journal8 theme which uses 'superfish' module for main menu. Right now I have this:

[image]

When I hover over parent menu item i get sub-menu opened.

**What I want to get is:**

1. No effect on hover (no sub-menu opening)
2. On click: going to new page **AND sub-menu stay opened all the time**
3. Also, when I enter any category like: **'tennis'** (which is in the sub-menu of parent-menu **'sport'**) the **'sport'** sub-menu stay opened.

The example of what I want to get you have on [this site](http://www.b92.net/).
Try to click on sport to see how it works...
Hope that somebody could help or have similar problem :)

Comment: If you don't want the submenu to open, why are you using a submenu? Just remove the submenu

Comment: I just put it on the list what I want to achieve, to be easier for people to understand the issue... It is not a problem to remove it, but I need it to open on the next page...

Comment: I understand what you are saying... I just wanted to ask for tips and suggestions, not expecting from you to do this for me :)

Answer (score 0):

on sports page add jquery

i assume your menu like this

```
<a href="/sports" id="sports">Sports</a>
```

and just add like below

```
    <style>
    .active
    {
    background-color:#FFEC00;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    $('#car').addClass('active');
    </script>
```